# What is the use of this cord on my backpack?

Tags: backpacks

I have a feeling this can come in handy but I don't know why exactly has this been provided.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Erik I added another picture to the question. Is that the angle you asked for? The pack is Walkabout 65 from Halti, a respectable local brand from Finland. Not sure if this model is still available.

Comment: No I was looking for the opposite side as the one you just posted.

Comment: @Erik lol, total misunderstanding on my part. You can google the model and find images for it very easily. Anyways now I know I can even ignore this as it might not be too useful for me. I wasn't using the bag efficiently till now e.g. tying the sleeping pad to the bottom of the pack while it is designed to carry the pad on the top as it shows in the picture. This made me wonder if I was doing other things wrong as well?

Comment: No worries about the camera angle. Maybe I can't see the same Google results as you because I'm in Idaho, or because I don't speak Finnish. I can't seem to find anything online except [this](https://www.xxl.fi/halti-walkabout-65-rinkka/p/1111462_1_style) which doesn't show that cord.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real range of answers is only limited by your imagination. There are an innumerable amount of things you can do with a spare bit of cordage. One use that I can see for it in your picture is as a replacement for your rubber band around the tent poles.

**The most likely *intended* use is to secure the sharp end of an ice tool.** The nylon loop at the bottom right of your second picture is to secure the head of the ice tool. If you threaded the head of the tool through there it would probably just reach the abrasion resistant batch that the cord in question is mounted. This would also allow the compression strap to secure the handle of the ice tool, and keep the sharp bottom end of the ice tool firmly next to the extra thick abrasion resistant patch. Granted this would also point the sharp end of the ice tool towards your arms which probably isn't ideal....

---

The OP posted a comment that identified the pack as a Walkabout 65 made by Halti. I wasn't able to find that exact pack on their website, but I did find their [Discover 45](https://www.halti.com/collections/backpacks/products/discover-45-pack) pack.

[image: Discover 45 pack detail]

As you can see they have the same type of cord directly above the tool loop like I'd expect to secure the end of ice tools. I think the apparent forward angle I saw in the OP's photo was an artifact, and the cord is for securing the end of an ice tool.

Comment: I had the same thought: This is used on many packs for ice-axe fastening, but I have never seen it at such an odd position. Would be interesting if there was any definite instructions for that particular pack on what this is for and/or how to use this.

Comment: @imsodin I agree with everything you said, which is why I asked for the name of the pack in a comment above. This is what makes the most sense to me at the moment but it is odd enough to make me wonder what I might be missing.

Answer (score 3):

Given that it is above the mesh pocket at the side, my guess is that it is for walking/ski poles.

If you need to put the poles away for a short time (for example, a traverse using your ice axe, a river crossing), you don't need to go to the trouble of loosening the compression straps (the ones holding the tent poles in the photos above).

Answer (score -1):

Well maybe that ...... but due to the placemen is used to attach your backpack to the carry on ( the one with weels ) you attach it to the long metal pice that is retractil

Answer (score -1):

Mesh pockets are often used for water bottles, the mesh is to allow the condensation on the outside of the bottle to evaporate and not collect inside a regular pocket.

Given the proximity to the mesh pocket, the strap may be intended for lashing the top of the bottle to the pack. Lashing the top of the water bottle helps keep it from moving around or from falling out altogether.

Depending on your activities, this may or may not be necessary. So to paraphrase @Erik, use it for whatever you need.